# Atom randomly open files in new window (in stead of in new tab)

Tags: atom-editor

The issue is that when i allready have a project opened in Atom and i try to open another project (weather i use `atom .` from the command line or *file* > *Open* from the Atom menu) Atom seemingly random opens the project in a new window instead of in a new tab of the current instance.

I'm really getting fed-up with this because i don't want to navigate between three Atom instances to switch between projects. I just want all my projects in one Atom instance and switch between tabs.

*Sometimes* however Atom opens a new project in a new tab of the current instance, but unfortunatly that is the minority.

Does anybody else have this issue or know how i can force Atom to always open a new project in a new tab?

I'm on MacOS 10.13.6 and Atom 1.29.0

Below a screencast of the issue:
[image]

Since it's pretty hard to see, i justt do `atom .` from two directories

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in the Atom help output, there's a logic to it.

> ```
> Usage:
>   atom [options] [path ...]
>   atom file[:line[:column]]
> ```
>
> One or more paths to files or folders may be specified. If there is an
>   existing Atom window that contains all of the given folders, the paths
>   will be opened in that window. Otherwise, they will be opened in a new
>   window.

However, you can use the `--add` flag to add files or folders to the *last used window* of Atom.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but that add's the project to the navigator bar on the left. I want the project to open in a new tab (like sometimes happens)

Comment: Folders will always be added to the sidebar, because a folder can't be opened in a tab – tabs are for files. Files will be opened in a new tab. If the file is not part of the previously opened project, then it's parent folder will be added to the sidebar.